# Sharing Article On Facebook, but picks random image than the one set at <meta property="og:image"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-opengraph

It's ASP.NET-MVC. Trying to share an article on facebook.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@RenderSection("Title", false)   
<title>@(helper.Title)</title>
```

Details.cshtml:

```
@section Title{
<title>@(helper.ArticleName) - @(helper.Narrator)</title>
<meta property="og:title"   content="@(helper.ArticleName)" />
<meta property="og:type"    content="article" />
<meta property="og:image"   content="@(helper.ArticleImage)" />
<meta property="og:url"     content="@(helper.ArticleUrl)" />
}
```

On Facebook, it displays the main logo of the site, which is placed under `"~\Content\Images\Page"` folder, instead of the image set `"@(helper.ArticleImage)"`. I tried to put the image's url: `https://fastercvstorage.............../115d26b0-60c0-7bc6-8f11-08d12d2dff6a.jpg`. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: It will sometimes take some time for the og: tags to work on Facebook, for reasons I am unaware of. Maybe the debugger can help, you haven't tried it already: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I agree with Tobias, also make sure your app_id or facebook page identifier is in the metadata for best results.